# VB.NET: Modifying non-text file as text without ruining it

Tags: vb.net, text, character-encoding

I need my application to find and modify a text string in a .swp file (generated by VBA for SOLIDWORKS). If I open said file as text in Notepad++, most of the text looks like this (this is an excerpt):

[image]

Meaning there is readable text, and symbols that appear as NUL, BEL, EXT and so on, depending on selected encoding. If I make my changes via Notepad++ (finding and changing "1.38" to "1.39"), there are no issues, the file can be opened via SOLIDWORKS and is still recognized as valid. After all, I don't need to modify these non-readable bits. However, if I do the same modification in my VB.NET application,

```
    Dim filePath As String = "D:\OneDrive\Desktop\launcher macro.swp"
    Dim fileContents As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("1.38", "1.39")
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContents, Encoding.UTF8)
```

then the file gets corrupted, and is no longer recognized by SOLIDWORKS. I suspect this is because ReadAllText and WriteAllText cannot handle whatever data is in these non-readable bits.

I tried many different encodings, but it seems to make no difference. I am not sure how Notepad++ does it, but I can't seem to get the same result in my VB.NET application.

Can someone advise?

Comment: Is the value of fileContents as expected?  Does that match what  you see when you open it in Notpad++?

Comment: @Hursey, it is difficult to tell, but I don't think it is the same. I get a lot of vbNullChar in that string.

Comment: The problem is likely the fact that VB considers a null character to be a string terminator, so I'm guessing that you're only saving until that first null character. I wonder whether you might need to read the data in binary form, convert that to characters using the appropriate `Encoding`, create a `StringBuilder` and then manipulate that before reversing the process to save. Not sure whether that would get around the issue or not.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thank you very much, that worked perfectly. Please copy-paste what you wrote as an answer to this question, so that I can give you a proper upvote!

Comment: I don't think that there's enough specific information in my comment to warrant an answer. You should post your own answer based on your actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jmcilhinney, this is a solution that worked for me - reading file as bytes, converting to string, and then saving, using ANSI formatting:

```
    Dim file_name As String = "D:\OneDrive\Desktop\launcher macro.swp"

    Dim fs As New FileStream(file_name, FileMode.Open)
    Dim binary_reader As New BinaryReader(fs)
    fs.Position = 0
    Dim bytes() As Byte = binary_reader.ReadBytes(binary_reader.BaseStream.Length)
    Dim fileContents As String = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes)
    fileContents = fileContents.Replace("1.38", "1.39")
    binary_reader.Close()
    fs.Dispose()

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file_name, fileContents, Encoding.Default)
```